# How to get names of all installed webcams and microphones using VB6 code or any other programing language?

Tags: vb6, webcam, microphone, drivers, device

I want to know how to get names of all installed webcams and microphones using VB6 code? Or maybe someone could show how it is done in any other programming language because now I don't have any clue from what to start.

Answer (score -2):

You can type in a command prompt

```
Driverquery /v
```

and parse the output.

```
sc query type= all
```

also lists drivers AND services.

Also

```
wmic sysdriver get /format:list
```